# Disabling primary display in Fedora 22 (without primary display visible)

Tags: fedora, display, display-settings

My primary display isn't working and I'm using a monitor. Unfortunately, Fedora 22 doesn't seem to pick up on this and acts as though I had two displays working simultaneously. As all system settings / the control panel, as well as several programs, launch on the primary display, I cannot get to some of the files I need (eg, Libre Calc), let alone adjust settings.

How can I do this via command line, or through some shortcut?

Comment: --off did the trick. Thanks. Want to post this as an answer so I can check it?

Comment: If you want to launch terminal and it is not visible, try using super+arrows to move window to other side

Comment: You also try disconnecting the problematic monitor and restarting the OS

Comment: Same for me occurred when I tried to use Cinnamon on Fedora for first time. Using the "trick" of turning off the problematic monitor, allowed me to start Cinnamon on "good" monitor. Then, I turned on problematic monitor, and it was recognizes. So I turned it the primary monitor again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to set your primary display with `xrandr`. First query your displays by just executing

```
xrandr
```

Then set the primary with e.g.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary
```

Or disable the other display with

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --off.
```

Or you could write a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.